# SQL query to select prior record based on value

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

Using SQL Server 2012 Express.

The SQL query below is horribly slow and need advice to enhance performance or do it more efficiently.

It queries a table called `PriceDaily` and queries the `Date` column for a given date e.g. `2009/11/27` (the date can be any date and will actually be determined by a variable).

Sorted by date, it then needs to move X records up (+X) or down (-X) and return the value in that record for the date field. e.g. for -5, it will move 5 records up and return the date value.

e.g. it will return `2009/11/20` If a portion of the table looks like this (since `2009/11/20` is 5 records above `2009/11/27`):

```
2009/11/20
2009/11/23
2009/11/24
2009/11/25
2009/11/26
2009/11/27
2009/11/30
2009/12/01
2009/12/02
2009/12/03
2009/12/04
```

The query to be optimised:

```
with Records AS
(
   select 
       row_number() over(order by date) as 'row', 
       * 
   from [NIG03].[dbo].[PriceDaily]
)
select Date 
from records
where row = (SELECT Top 1 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Date DESC) AS Row
             FROM [NIG03].[dbo].[PriceDaily]
             WHERE [NIG03].[dbo].[PriceDaily].Date<'2009/11/27'
             ORDER BY Date) - X + 1
```

Any advice on how to optimise this query will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* express this using only window functions:

```
select pd.*,
       max(case when date = '2009-11-27' then seqnum end) as date_seqnum
from (select pd.*,
             row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum
      from PriceDaily pd
     ) pd
where seqnum = date_seqnum - X + 1;
```

For this query (and your query), I think the issue for performance is that you need an index on `date`:

```
create index idx_pricedaily_date on PriceDaily(date);
```

There is an alternative approach (which will also benefit from the index):

```
select pd.*
from PriceDaily pd
where date >= '2009-11-27'
order by date
offset X rows fetch first 1 row only;
```

Of course, you need to adjust the offset to and the direction of the comparison in the `where` for different values of `X`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, will create index. how to go in opposite direction, since OFFSET clause may not be negative.

Comment: @Nelus . . . You change the direction of the comparison, change the `order by` to  `order by date desc` and use the absolute value of the offset.

Comment: it runs 1400% faster now, using alternative approach. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try following,

```
declare @date date = '2009/11/27'
declare @up int = -5
with Records AS
(
    select row_number() over(order by date) as 'row', 
            * 
    from [NIG03].[dbo].[PriceDaily]
)

select Date from records
where row=((select row from record where Date = @date) + (@up))
```